# Passing an object prop to onSelect callback not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I'm using a react-bootstrap dropdown. As per the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/), the `eventKey` prop will be passed to the `onSelect` handler when a dropdown item is selected.

I'm trying to set `eventKey` to an object, and have that passed to my `handleSelect(e)` handler, but when I `console.log()` the value passed to my handler, it gives me a string `[object Object]`.

My component looks like this:

```
const CustomDropdown = props => {
  function handleSelect(e) {
    console.log(e); 
    //I expect this to print { name: 'genre', label: 'Genres' } but 
    //it prints '[object Object]'
  }

  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle as={React.Button} variant="link" id="dropdown-basic">
        {props.text}
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
        {props.choices.map((choice, i) => (    //choices is an array of objects
          <Dropdown.Item
            key={i}
            eventKey={choice}        //The object I'm passing in. See below
            onSelect={handleSelect}>
            {choice.label}
          </Dropdown.Item>
        ))}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};
```

The `choice` object looks like this:

```
{
  name: 'genre',
  label: 'Genres',
}
```

However, if I replace my `onSelect={handleSelect}` prop with an arrow function `onSelect={() => handleSelect(choice)}`, the object is correctly passed to handleSelect, like I want. Why does the arrow function method pass the object, while the original method does not?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, had to use the `onSelect={() => handleSelect(choice)}` workaround as well. I think some stringifying issue is going on.